# Hermite interpolation formula

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, hermite-polynomials, interpolation-theory

Now a very trivial question about this book [Ralston: A first course in numerical analysis](http://62.182.86.140/main/903000/4bb55429c193eb542401a75bdd262d18/%28International%20series%20in%20pure%20and%20applied%20mathematics%29%20Anthony%20Ralston_%20Philip%20Rabinowitz%20-%20A%20first%20course%20in%20numerical%20analysis-McGraw-Hill%20%20%281978%29.pdf) the Hermite formula example, how it follows $$\frac{-1}{32768}<E(0.60)<\frac{-1}{2^{23}}$$ from this: $p_n(x),p_r(x)$ and the tables of $\ln(x)$ and $1/x$ at the points $0.4,0.5,0.7$ and $0.8$ ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I like "Herimte"!! What have you tried?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Me too! I wanted to use $(3.7-13)$ but I've failed to find the right $\xi$ for the insertion into $f^{(n+r)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is, per the cited formula and $n=r=4$,
$$
E(0.6)=\frac{f^{(8)}(\xi)}{8!}(0.1)^4(0.2)^4
$$
and $f^{(8)}(\xi)=-7!\xi^{-8}$, $\xi\in[0.4,0.8]$. This gives a bound to the error as
$$
E(0.6)=-\frac{1}{8\cdot \xi^8}\frac{2^4}{10^8}\in -\frac1{2^{15}}[2^{-8},1],
$$
which is the claim.

Comment: Which book is good like Ralston is but much more modern ? Could you kindly recommend to me 2 such books ?

Comment: Dear Lutz, could you please have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4610121/algebraic-equivalent-interpolation-formulae) ?